# SonarQube permission template does not work properly

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

I have an issue with SonarQube permission template which is not applied when the project is created.

**Scenario:**

- Set permissions template with pattern `.*(rlsrde|simple-template|smcportal).*`
- Run sonar analyse with the new project which has key `com.something:smcportal-commons:origin/something`

I thought that pattern which contains string smcportal would be mapped by smcportal string from the created project.

It's strange that Default Permissions template was also not applied.

SonarQube Version 5.6

Comment: Which permissions have been applied to the project ?

Comment: BROWSE: Users 0, Groups 0 ;SEE SOURCE CODE: Users 0, Groups 0
;ADMINISTER ISSUES: Users 0, Groups 0
;ADMINISTER: Users 0, Groups 0
;EXECUTE ANALYSIS: Users 0, Groups 0

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam any idea, please?

Comment: What is the content of the permission template ?

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam please see https://postimg.org/gallery/32ik26qzk/